# Display Image from Odata in Table View

Tags: swift4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVWf4.png)I am trying to create an app based on shopping cart with **swift 4**, display product list from oData in a Table View, one of the element of odata contains URL of Image .

with below codes i am trying to generate the URL in picUrl variable

```
var picUrl = String()
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! FUIContactCell

        let product = self.entities[indexPath.row]

picUrl = ("https://\(self.hurl)\(product.pictureUrl! as String)"   )

 if let url = URL(string: picUrl){

        downloadImage(url: url)
}

cell.detailImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Image.png")
cell.detailImage = self.imageView.glyphImage


   func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            completion(data, response, error)
            }.resume()
    }

    func downloadImage(url: URL) {
        //print("Download Started")
        getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in
         //   guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
          print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
           print("Download Finished")
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {

                self.imageView = (UIImage(data: data!))!

                }
        }
    }
```

downloadImage(url: url) calls the image from url.

but somehow i am getting attached error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYbXR.png)

Comment: Error is resolved ,able to download image but somehow its not displaying in App...!!

Comment: If I am using a random image from some URL it display but this image from oData doesn't . Not sure what exactly I am missing.